# Как конвертировать .ogg в .wav nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, аудио, поиск-библиотек

Мне нужно конвертировать .ogg или же буффер в .wav. какие библиотеки могут помочь и как именно с их помощью мне это сделать?

Comment: https://cloudmersive.medium.com/how-to-convert-audio-to-wav-in-node-js-bfc82c842f10